# How to improve performance of a Merge statement having Update in it

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, plsql

We have a MERGE STATEMENT on 2 tables and our batch job runs daily.
The issue is the Merge statement sometimes takes around 20-25 minutes and sometimes it takes
around 50-60 minutes for updating same volume of data.

```
MERGE INTO /*+ ENABLE_PARALLEL_DML PARALLEL (${DOP}) */ TAB1 Subpartition  (SUBAPARTITION_KEY2) A 
         USING  ${TAB2} B
         ON (A.ROWID = B.R1 and B.subpartition_key=SUBAPARTITION_KEY1)
         WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET change_status_code = B.change_status_code
```

Also even if i am creating index on TAB2 on R1 field ,the explain plan doesn't show index being used.

Could anyone suggest what should be done here..
Daily around 4-5 million records get updated

Comment: For some reason, I think a factor of 2 might be due to other activity on the system -- say locks on tables/rows/pages.  You can check the execution plans for runs and see if anything changes.  Often changes in execution plans, though, have a much bigger impact on performance.

Comment: No...There is not any kind of locks on table etc.  One thing is that we are doing gather stats on table on weekly basis ,and our batch jobs are running daily...And there are many partitons/subpartitions on the table as its having huge data

Comment: Did you try a normal update vs Merge?Do you see any difference in the explain plan. Couldn't see INSERT for the merge statement.

Comment: No...i didnt try normal update...We were having a delete and insert statement in place for this.(about an year ago)..Since the 2 DML statements were taking huge time ,thats why we replaced delete/insert with MERGE statement ...However while testing the implementation for merge ,i checked Update and it was taking more time then Merge..Thats why we opted for Merge

Comment: what's the number of rows and size of subpartition of TAB1 ? and it looks like ${TAB2} is a subquery, can you check if that is taking time ? Also, have you tried turning it into a correlated update statement ?

Comment: TAB1 and TAB2 both are tables...TAB2 table is not having any indexes as we are creating it for this Merge operation only...Number of rows in TAB1 is around 4-5 millions.

Comment: why are you joining on rowid ? => "A.ROWID = B.R1"

Comment: because TAB2 has been created on the basis of ROWID from TAB1...First we are identifying the records to update and creating  TAB2 using ROWID from TAB1..And while updating the same records joining on the basis of that field

Comment: I found this in an article on google..   Any suggestion w.rt Hash area?                                                                     
 you do not need a primary key for merge and to merge such large sets with eachother, indexes will be "not useful", what will be useful will be a large hash area size (8i) or pga_aggregate_target (9i)

Comment: you should never store one table's rowid into another table.. i would suggest if you are fetching data into tab2 from tab1, create a index in TAB2, on the same columns as which are present in TAB1, and then do a index merge join

Answer (score 0):

The hint must come directly after the first keyword.

Change this:

```
MERGE INTO /*+ ENABLE_PARALLEL_DML PARALLEL (${DOP}) */ ...
```

To this:

```
MERGE /*+ ENABLE_PARALLEL_DML PARALLEL (${DOP}) */ INTO  ...
```